# How to parse SOAP xml in sql server and show to table format

Tags: sql

the webservice returned SOAP xml result, i would like to change the format to table in SQL server

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <MemberInformationResponse xmlns="http://www.ucr.com.hk">
            <MemberInformationResult>
                <Code>0</Code>
                <Description>Get Member Info Success </Description>
                <MemberCode>9997</MemberCode>
                <MemberCardCode>9997</MemberCardCode>
                <MemberTypeCode>GOLD2020</MemberTypeCode>
                <MemberTypeName1>Gold Member 2020</MemberTypeName1>
                <MemberTypeName2>Gold Member 2020</MemberTypeName2>
                <OldMemberTypeCode>SilverLINE</OldMemberTypeCode>
                <OldMemberTypeName1>Silver Member(LINE)</OldMemberTypeName1>
                <OldMemberTypeName2>Silver Member(LINE)</OldMemberTypeName2>
                <LoginID>9997</LoginID>
                <Name1>SilverLINE</Name1>
                <Name2>SilverLINE</Name2>
                <Sex>0</Sex>
                <Mobile>99900099</Mobile>
                <Email>khso@kabu.com.hk</Email>
                <PromotionAlert>1</PromotionAlert>
                <YearOfBirth>2001</YearOfBirth>
                <MonthOfBirth>01</MonthOfBirth>
                <JoinDate>2016/03/01</JoinDate>
                <WorkingDistrict />
                <LivingDistrict />
                <ActivationCode>4516</ActivationCode>
                <ReferralMemberCardCode>0151136201</ReferralMemberCardCode>
                <Enabled>0</Enabled>
                <Point>1005</Point>
                <Point1>1005</Point1>
                <Point2>0</Point2>
                <AccumulatedAmount>16376.8</AccumulatedAmount>
                <ExpiryDate>2020/08/31</ExpiryDate>
                <ExtendExpiryDate>2021/08/31</ExtendExpiryDate>
                <PointRemain>0</PointRemain>
                <PointExpiryDate>----/--/--</PointExpiryDate>
            </MemberInformationResult>
        </MemberInformationResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I tried below script, but no result return.

```
declare @xmldata xml
SET @xmldata = *put above soap xml*
declare @readdoc as INT

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @readdoc OUTPUT, @xmldata , '<root xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />'

select Code, MemberCode
from OPENXML(@readdoc,'soap:Envelope/soap:Body/MemberInformationResponse/MemberInformationResult')
with
( 
    Code int 'Code',
    MemberCode [varchar](50) 'MemberCode'
)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @readdoc
GO
```

How to get output like this :
| Code | MemberCode |
| ---- | ---------- |
| 0    | 9997       |

please help to advise.  Thanks.

Comment: Looking at the doc the input to `sp_xml_preparedocument is `VARCHAR` not `XML`. Next use SELECT * instead of specific columns and experiment.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer....

I believe it's something to do with `MemberInformationResponse` being in yet another namespaces

I think the newer way to do this is use the methods of the XML data type

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms190798(v=sql.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Rather than `sp_xml_preparedocument` etc.

If you want to stick with `sp_xml_preparedocument`, I suggest you experiment with this. It produces an output and you can iteratively experiment with it.

```
declare @xmldata VARCHAR(8000)
SET @xmldata = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <MemberInformationResponse xmlns="http://www.ucr.com.hk">
            <MemberInformationResult>
                <Code>0</Code>
                <Description>Get Member Info Success </Description>
                <MemberCode>9997</MemberCode>
                <MemberCardCode>9997</MemberCardCode>
                <MemberTypeCode>GOLD2020</MemberTypeCode>
                <MemberTypeName1>Gold Member 2020</MemberTypeName1>
                <MemberTypeName2>Gold Member 2020</MemberTypeName2>
                <OldMemberTypeCode>SilverLINE</OldMemberTypeCode>
                <OldMemberTypeName1>Silver Member(LINE)</OldMemberTypeName1>
                <OldMemberTypeName2>Silver Member(LINE)</OldMemberTypeName2>
                <LoginID>9997</LoginID>
                <Name1>SilverLINE</Name1>
                <Name2>SilverLINE</Name2>
                <Sex>0</Sex>
                <Mobile>99900099</Mobile>
                <Email>khso@kabu.com.hk</Email>
                <PromotionAlert>1</PromotionAlert>
                <YearOfBirth>2001</YearOfBirth>
                <MonthOfBirth>01</MonthOfBirth>
                <JoinDate>2016/03/01</JoinDate>
                <WorkingDistrict />
                <LivingDistrict />
                <ActivationCode>4516</ActivationCode>
                <ReferralMemberCardCode>0151136201</ReferralMemberCardCode>
                <Enabled>0</Enabled>
                <Point>1005</Point>
                <Point1>1005</Point1>
                <Point2>0</Point2>
                <AccumulatedAmount>16376.8</AccumulatedAmount>
                <ExpiryDate>2020/08/31</ExpiryDate>
                <ExtendExpiryDate>2021/08/31</ExtendExpiryDate>
                <PointRemain>0</PointRemain>
                <PointExpiryDate>----/--/--</PointExpiryDate>
            </MemberInformationResult>
        </MemberInformationResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
'


declare @readdoc as INT

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @readdoc OUTPUT, @xmldata, '<root xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />'

select *
from OPENXML(@readdoc,'/soap:Envelope/soap:Body')

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @readdoc
GO
```